# How to add hatching by condition with GEOPANDAS and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I try to plot a map, where a value should define the type of hatching for each polygon.
I managed to get a hatch for the total plot, but not based on a condition.
Is there a way to do this with geopandas?
My code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

project_data = 'XXX'
border = gpd.read_file(f'{project_data}GIS/border.json')
data = gpd.read_file(f'{project_data}GIS/shape.json')

def marker(row, field):
    m = ''
    if (row[field] <= 0):
        m = ''
    elif (row[field] <= 0.5):
        m = '--'
    elif (row[field] <= 1):
        m = '/////'
    elif (row[field] <= 1.6):
        m = 'x'
    return m

data['UI_P45_M'] = data.apply(marker, field='UI_P45', axis=1)

field1 = 'AL_CUR_I'
hatch1 = 'UI_P45_M'
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('pink_r')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.axis('off')
border.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="black",
       ax=ax, zorder=2, linewidth=0.5)
data.plot(
column=field1, linewidth=0, norm=Normalize(0, 1.2),
cmap=cmap, ax=ax, hatch=hatch1, zorder=1
)

fig = plt.gcf()

plt.savefig(f'{project_data}results/hatched.pdf')
plt.close(fig)
```

I also tried to put a layer on top where I do the hatching like this:

```
border.plot(facecolor="none", edgecolor="black",
           ax=ax,  zorder=3, linewidth=0.5)

data.plot(
    column=field1, linewidth=0,norm=Normalize(0,1.2),
    cmap=cmap, ax=ax, zorder=1
)
data.plot(
    column=field1, linewidth=0, hatch=hatch1,
    facecolor='none',
    ax=ax, zorder=2
)
```

... but still it doesn't show up.
The picture that I get is this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plotting a geodataframe with polygon geometries leverages matplotlib's [Polygon artists](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html#matplotlib.patches.Polygon), so the `hatch` keyword argument is passed there.

From the Polygon docs, you can see that the hatch keyword is itself interpreted by [`matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch). From these docs:

> [**`set_hatch`**](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Patch.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch)(*hatch*)
>
> Set the hatching pattern.
>
> hatch can be one of:
>
> ```
> /   - diagonal hatching
> \   - back diagonal
> |   - vertical
> -   - horizontal
> +   - crossed
> x   - crossed diagonal
> o   - small circle
> O   - large circle
> .   - dots
> *   - stars
> ```
>
> Letters can be combined, in which case all the specified hatchings are done. If same letter repeats, it increases the density of hatching of that pattern.

So the issue is actually that you can't specify a column name as the hatch indicator. Instead, subset the data for each hatch type, then choose one of the valid hatches, e.g.:

```py
data.loc[some_criteria_1].plot(..., hatch='/')
data.loc[some_criteria_2].plot(..., hatch='|')
# etc
```

Comment: That is a good idea! I just zipped an dictionary and looped through it. Thank you, it works fine : )

Answer (score -1):

- question tags are **geopandas** so have used **folium** to generate choropleth
- details of approach can be found here https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html
- have used standard natural earth dataset to make a MWE

```
import geopandas as gpd
import folium
from folium.plugins import StripePattern

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).loc[
    lambda d: (d["continent"] == "Europe") & (~d["iso_a3"].isin(["-99", "RUS"]))
]
# classify countries into 4 with a label
gdf["fill_cat"] = pd.qcut(gdf["pop_est"], 4, labels=list("abcd"))

m = folium.Map(
    location=(gdf.total_bounds[[1, 3]].mean(), gdf.total_bounds[[0, 2]].mean()),
    height=300,
    width=500,
)
m.fit_bounds([gdf.total_bounds[[1, 0]].tolist(), gdf.total_bounds[[3, 2]].tolist()])

# category config
hatch_style = {
    "a": {"angle": 0, "color": "grey"},
    "b": {"angle": 45, "color": "red"},
    "c": {"angle": 90, "color": "green"},
    "d": {"angle": 135, "color": "blue"},
}
folium.GeoJson(
    gdf.__geo_interface__,
    tooltip=gpd.explore._tooltip_popup("tooltip", True, gdf),
    style_function=lambda p: {
        "color": hatch_style[p["properties"]["fill_cat"]]["color"],
        "weight": 1,
        "fillPattern": StripePattern(**hatch_style[p["properties"]["fill_cat"]]),
    },
).add_to(m)

m
```

[image]

Comment: how to save folim-maps to file? I cannot get it working with m.save('output_file')... do you know hot to inculde that in an matplotlibplot? that is actually what I need...

Comment: this isn't what the OP was asking about...